# Combining elements from 2 arrays in a specific order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 2 arrays

```
selectedERO[] = {"Device A, Device B, Device C"}

selectedLinks[] = { "Port A1 - Port B1, PortB2 - PortC1" )
```

What I want is this - essentialy a path from device A to device C in an array that looks like this

```
PotentialPath[] = {"DeviceA, Port A1, Port B1, DeviceB, PortB2 ,PortC1, DeviceC"}
```

Any inputs would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please add the the mentioned arrays and the wanted (valid) result.

Comment: Wanted valid result - Array [srs-rt3, srs-rt3:ge-0/1/0,atla-cr5:10/1/3,atla-cr5, atla-cr5:3/1/1, ornl-cr5:6/1/1, ornl-cr5 ]

Comment: and what is the rule behind?

Comment: So the arrays in the first part are consol.log output of two arrays SelectedLinks[] and SelectedERO[] I get the output from these arrays but I want them formatted like this Array [srs-rt3, srs-rt3:ge-0/1/0,atla-cr5:10/1/3,atla-cr5, atla-cr5:3/1/1, ornl-cr5:6/1/1, ornl-cr5 ]

Comment: Rule behind what?

Comment: i see a bunch of data, but no rule to combine the wanted result. what is the rule behind the combination of the result? how are the single parts stringed together?

Comment: Rule is:   {deviceA(srsrt3), firstPort(srs-rt3:ge-0/1/0), secondport(atla-cr5:10/1/3), deviceB(atla-cr5) firstPort(atla-cr5:3/1/1) , secondPort(ornl-cr5:6/1/1), deviceC (ornl-cr5)}

Comment: please add `SelectedLinks` and `SelectedERO` in text form to the question, and not a not separated output from the console.

Comment: @NinaScholz I just edited. This seems appropriate?

Comment: There is no JSON in your question. I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the goven strings and reassamble the result with inserting links between *ERO*.

```js
var selectedERO = "Device A, Device B, Device C",
    selectedLinks = "Port A1 - Port B1, PortB2 - PortC1",
    links = selectedLinks.split(', '),
    result = selectedERO.split(', ').reduce(function (a, b, i) {
        return [a].concat(links[i - 1].split(' - '), b).join(', ');
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the solution. However, I do not want the "-" given in selectedLinks, Just  Port A1, Port B1. Is there a way around it.